# Laravel Storage->get returns 500 Internal Server Error. 1 in 10 times

Tags: php, image, laravel, storage, internal-server-error

I have a little issue with getting a image from the storage into my html with laravel. Most of the time it works fine but sometimes I randomly seem to get a 500 Internal Server Error.

**HTML**

```
<div style="background:center no-repeat url(/profile/picture/{{Auth::user()->photo}});" class="img-circle m-b emp-img" alt="logo"></div>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('profile/picture/{image}', function($image = null){
    return App\Ratsys\StorageController::getProfilePicture($image);
});
```

**Method**

```
public static function getProfilePicture($file){
    return Storage::disk(self::$driver)->get('uploads/employee/picture/'.$file);
}
```

**Request header**

```
GET /profile/picture/img.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: ratsys.dev
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://ratsys.dev/dashboard
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkRMSTBTVUo1QWx1enMxS3FNUHI1MGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV3l1ZlBMSXRNbmo5TjBCZTkrZVRjK05NWkdycHR6MHh1NkZnTnNUUURtbFdYV0NJblwvZDBuQUtiRlFteWFEeEhWcjZkSjlPd1kyOCtOUlwvV3BIMkprUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDIxY2E2ZWExNGZlNTljNTQ2OTdiYWFkMjYwYTU2Y2YzZDMwMDI5ZDRmZDIxNjYxYTgxYjc2ODkwNjUxZWE4NyJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFHUGlhR3BRQnlaM2dDeGdzUDB4TkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoienMwd1NvZjdNdStJMVA3VkE5dDhwS3dhTFRuK2I1ZlJaS1F1bGl6TmNUUklONTZEbW04T3RRNFFpZklDcFR3TjNGOUZxYzhKNktvWW1LcnFudmRiRmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjE5MGNiNzcwNjM5MTk2Yjg2MThkZTQ4NzY1NmNkOTUyYTVmODM2ZDBiZjE3YjA0NDAxNzQwMGY0Yjk0MWVkZWEifQ%3D%3D
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 07:23:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal about the cause of the issue?

Comment: @arkascha Nothing much checked wamp\logs\apache_error.txt and last error in there is from march 25.

Comment: Are you sure that is the error log file used by the http server? I have no experience with a MS-Windows environment, but that path looks funny to me. And I would expect each http 500 status code sent out to generate an entry in the error log file. _Except if you disabled error logging, that is._

Comment: I had the same issue once, my problem was filesize, the filesize was greater than the maxfilesize declared in php.ini when the error is present.

Comment: @arkascha Yes i think it is httpd conf says ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

Comment: Well, then I would expect _that_ file to be the error log you want to take a look into? Note that `apache_error.log` and `apache_error.txt` are two different things.

Comment: @arkascha Was a typo on my part. c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log is the file i visited. I made virtual host now with a custom error log and gona try to reproduce the errror and see if i get something in there.

Comment: You also want to check how php is actually used in your http server environment. php errors will only be sent into the http servers error log file if php is operated as a module inside the http server. That indeed is the typical setup, but sometimes other setups are used with other logging strategies.

Comment: @arkascha Took a while to get the error again but it hapend. ill i see is 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2016:11:00:08 +0200] "GET /profile/picture/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 8970

Comment: No, that is _not_ the error log file, that is the access log file.

Comment: @arkascha Error log is still empty for the new vhost. That was the only logged thing.

Comment: It cannot be empty after a restart of the http server, the restart itself is logged into the error log file. So this means that either error logging is completely disabled on your system which does not make any sense at all, or that you are still looking at the wrong file. Either way you want to solve this issue, you cannot develop php without monitoring that error log file.